# Pageable not giving expected results with @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: spring, jpa, pagination, pageable

We are dealing with `@ManyToMany` relation with Users and Roles and want to have pagination to get all the Users with associated Roles by using Pageable interface. It is only considering the records count for pagination on the User Table and  Roles table record is not considered. But ideally in RDBMS the actual record count would be after flattening the result of join between Users and Roles table.

[image: Refer Table relationship]

When working with `Pageable` in `findAll` method and passing the page configuration as below :

`pageno: 0 and pageSize:1`

```
    Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(0, 1);
    userRepository.findAll(paging);
```

It is giving the result as below

[image: Refer Response of pagination]

Technically there are 3 records when we flatten the result but pageable is considering this as 1 record which is not correct. Is this intended behavior?

Is there a way where we can get the pagination after flattening the result set of query?

Comment: You are calling the `userRepository`. As far as `userRepository` is concerned, one `user` is `one` count. May be you want to create a `UserRole` entity and `UserRoleRepository` and it will give you the flatten record and it will count this as 3 records

Comment: Thanks @KavithakaranKanapathippillai for the very quick response, suggestion and for editing .Will try this approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is intended. Data is mapped to Java objects as nested objects. Hence, pageable of 5 user records will return 5 users irrespective of number of roles each user has.

To restrict pagination based on record count by combination of user and role, you have to add join between user and role to the query in repository method and fetch columns from both user and role (like we do in SQL).

Below code works for me

User entity

```
public class User
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userId;
    
    @NonNull
    @Column(unique = true, name= "user_name")
    private String userName;
    
    @NonNull
    private String password;
    
    @NonNull
    private boolean status;
    
    @NonNull
    private boolean passwordExpired;
    
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role_name", referencedColumnName = "name") })

    @BatchSize(size = 20)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
//Get and set
}
```

Role Entity

```
public class Role  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Id
    @Column(length = 50,unique=true)
    private String name;
//get and set
    
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
{   
    @Query(value="SELECT u.userName,r.name FROM User u left join u.roles r")
    public ArrayList<User> findByrole(Pageable paging);
}
```

Service method

```
public ArrayList<User> findByrole() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(0, 4);
        return uRepo.findByrole(paging);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @sridhar For the quick response and sample example with explanations .. Will try this approach ...

Comment: @ManojKumar let me know if it solved your problem. Also, mark it as answer if this actually solved your problem

Comment: Yes Sridhar , it has really helped me to think forward and achieve the solution. I was little bit in confusion, to decide whether to use join or create a UserRole Join Table repository as suggested by  Kavithakaran Kanapathippillai   above.. Any way It helped me a lot and  I am marking it as answer.. Thanks for the suggestions